# Protect Changing Slug in Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Asp.net Mvc 4.5.1 with C#.

I want to protect url slug such as;

[host]/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug} ( Let's assume template is like this. )

**[host]/Article/Detail/5/Mvc-is-awesome** ( This is correct url )
But users can manupulate it, an example;
**[host]/Article/Detail/5/I-can-write-whatever-I-want**

So I want to protect slug. When user enter the url;
[host]/Article/Detail/5/I-can-write-whatever-I-want
Routing must route url to correct one;
[host]/Article/Detail/5/Mvc-is-awesome ( This is correct url )

How can I do that? Any ideas, best practices ?

*Not: I think similar question should asked before but I can't find it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **id** and the **slug** specified, you can have in your controller logic for getting the correct slug and if the

> specified-slug != correct-slug

you can do

> return RedirectToAction("Article","Detail", new { id = id, slug = correct-slug });

In RouteConfig, you also need to specify the transformation logic to get the desired URL format (by interpreting the *slug* parameter).